# can i link openstack to other servers maybe?

Tags: cloud, openstack, private-cloud

is there any way I can link OpenStack to other servers and what I mean by that in my case I have a pfsense server for my firewall config and Zimbra as my mail server and traumas as storage server all in VirtualBox obviously and I have OpenStack server so my question here can I link Zimbra and pfsense and truenas to OpenStack server please guys answer me I'm in so much trouble can't find answer for this anywhere on the internet. if yes can you please link me useful articles

Answer (score 1):

You can link Traumas(storage server) as backend NAS device with openstack glance.

Pfsense can be used within openstack, you need to import pfsense as a image on openstack and use it. You cannot link existing Pfsence vm with openstack.